# Eclipse 4.2 Shared Plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bundle, p2

I have been searching on how to do this for a while now, and it seems like this has changed multiple times in recent history with no direction on how to do it in the present.

I administer a bunch of eclipse installations on a network (developers computers). Right now they are standalone installations (all have the same plugins installed locally).

I would like to be able to install the base eclipse on all these machines and have each one of them go to a central location on the network to get their plugins. That way I can add/update/remove plugins in one location instead of multiple individual computers.

Can anyone tell me how to do this with the latest version of Eclipse. I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Devlopers (Juno 4.2) http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr1

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

share a folder from a computer to all the machines and create work space on that folder

Comment: So, everyone would start an Eclipse instance over the network? Have you tried this? What is the approximate startup time for a WTP distribution in this case?

Comment: wouldn't we have a bunch of plugin folders in the workspaces? I am looking for a way to have 1 plugin folder. Sorry if I am misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Create a network folder and install eclipse and all plugins there. Team can map to network drive and copy over standard eclipse and plugins to there local drives and every body gets the same set.

Comment: I really don't want the "users" to have to copy over a new eclipse directory every time I update/add/remove a plugin. I rather the changes take place when they restart eclipse. Any way you know of to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a profile in [Yoxos](https://yoxos.eclipsesource.com) and distribute the launcher to the individual computers.

EDIT

Public profiles are free and should be sufficient unless you

- want to distribute private features
- want to save on bandwidth

EDIT

I read up a little on .eclipseextension you mentioned.
You can achieve same in p2 through the [dropins](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins) folder.

Share the dropins folder of your server installation over the network.
Sync the dropins folders of your client installations with shared folder.

Comment: really don't want to have to buy another product to do this. Eclipse 3.2 had .eclipseextension that kind of did this, but with p2 they either got away with it, it doesn't work like it used to, or is just not suggested. p2 has bundle pooling but I haven't found anything on how to actually set that up.

Comment: Public will not work in my case. Is there now no way to do this in eclipse?

Comment: Updated my answer to mention p2 dropins.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is [a current weakness of P2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Shared_Install), that is hopefully addressed soon. Currently, there is no good solution.

Options in the meantime:

- Plugins and Features carry their deployment information inside them. On a build for plugins and features ['advice' for the installer](http://www.toedter.com/blog/?p=79) can be added. This advice can change the update sites that will be deployed to the P2 system. This option requires that you create an outermost package that contains *everything required* and alter all update sites that are contained to point to your deployment location. This requires you to alter the distribution units. Lots of hard work.
- Use the [commercial Nexus Pro P2 proxy service](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/_proxy_p2_repositories.html). This service is an HTTP proxy server that intercepts requests to the outside world, caching calls and answering them locally. This will allow you to restrict what users can install by blocking calls to the outside, but costs money.

Comment: How does proxying the repositories help in this case? Each setup will still have to be administered individually.

Comment: The proxying is only a side-effect. Nexus Pro proxies remote P2s and renders its local content as a P2. This speeds the build up quite a bit.